# Navigation issue : Navigate to screen by skipping in between screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I have three components. let say A,B,C . now I want to navigate from A to C through B

**A(Source)**—>B—>**C(Destination)**

But in that process i dont want to show component B. It should look like that user has directly go from A to C . I want to navigate like that because component C is for view only with one back button which must go to component B

So can I navigate without showing in between component/s.

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739126/scroll-to-a-specific-element-using-html/56936579#56936579 check this link

Comment: I dont think it will solve my issue.

Comment: Are you using react-navigation 5x? I think you can achieve similar result by following this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#push

Answer (score 1):

A possible Solution could be to tell your BackButton to navigate to Screen B always.

And then just Navigate from A to C and on C backbutton to B.

If it needs to be from the Android backbutton then check this link maybe:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/

It has to be in a StackNavigator tho - check the part "goBack".

~Faded

Comment: It will be  push not pop