# How to open from <a> an specific part of a html document?

Tags: javascript, html

I have these `<a href>` buttons  in index html and I want to open different pages but when I press the link I need to open the specific part of the second document which is an `<article>`.

I'm trying to develop an index.html where I have buttons with articles (like a blog) and when I click in the button it opens the document where the article is written for example technology.html each button goes to the specific article that I have written in that section, not loading from top the document.

Comment: That's what the "#identifier" part of a URL is for. Give the `<article>` elements unique "id" values, then use that string after "#" in the links.

Comment: If they're in a blog, the `<article>` elements may already have id values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to a specific Element Using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739126/scroll-to-a-specific-element-using-html)

Comment: Your answer is already there check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481911/linking-to-a-specific-part-of-a-web-page)

Comment: Do you want to load another HTML file inside `index.html` ? If so, then you're probably looking for [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: I have tried with <a href="#article"> and it loads the article but with no CSS format

Answer (score 4):

Set the `id` attribute on the element you’d like to link to, and include that ID at the end of your URL path, denoted by a `#`.

So, to link to `<article id=“blog1”>` on `www.example.com`, your anchor tag would be:

```html
<a href=“http://www.example.com#blog1”>Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

**What about this:-**

If you want link's which redirect or target to current page element's then use targeting type URL's e.g. `href="#element_to_target"` and Here is a working example of your question.

```css
article{ height: 500px; width: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }
article p{ font-weigth: bold; }
#first{ background: red; color: #fff; }
#second{ background: blue; color: #fff; }
#third{ background: green; color: #fff; }
.fixed{ position: fixed; top: 3px; }
.fixed a{ background: #dcdcdc; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #666; }
```

```html
 <html style="scroll-behavior: smooth;">
  <div class="fixed">
    <a href="#first">First</a>
    <a href="#second">second</a>
    <a href="#third">third</a>
  </div>
  <article id="first"><p>Hi I'm first</p></article>
  <article id="second"><p>Hi I'm second</p></article>
  <article id="third">Hi I'm third</p></article>
</html>
```

If this is not working for you then add your URL before `#_type_identifier` e.g. `href="http://yourdomain.or/path#element"`.

Hope this will helpful for you, thank you.