# Wanna link button to a specific part of the same page in using html CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make website where when you click on a button on the home page it takes you down to a specific part of the page.

The home page has three buttons in the same div (length conversion, weight conversion, more) by clicking on the button"length conversion" it'll take you to the part where you convert the length (km-m etc)

Comment: Hi, I think this answer's your query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739126/scroll-to-a-specific-element-using-html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to a specific Element Using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739126/scroll-to-a-specific-element-using-html)

Answer (score 1):

add ids to the div where you want go.
then in Button use `<a href="id of your div">`
then it'll scroll to the specific part when you click on the button