# How to use a button to navigate to a specific point on a page

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm relatively new to form development and need to use a button click event to navigate to a specific location on a page. For example, we are creating a restaurant menu, with a submenu. The submenu will navigate the page to appetizers, entrees, desserts etc. All menu items will be kept on a single scrolling page. For testing purposes, I currently have a button called btnAppetizers, and group box located at (260,730). I would like btnAppetizers to navigate to this groupbox on click. I have not been able to find anything else online explaining how to do this.

Edit for clarity: This is using a C# Windows Form Application, not HTML
Alternatively, a button with the function "return to top" would also provide similar functionality. The button when clicked would bring the user to a specific point (top of the page)

Comment: I think this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739126/scroll-to-a-specific-element-using-html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to a specific Element Using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739126/scroll-to-a-specific-element-using-html)