# Scroll from element to an another component's element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scroll

I have this problem for days and I could not figure this out (also im pretty new in Angular). My goal would be to have an element in a component like this. Lets called this **A element**:

```
<button (click)="scroll('anotherComponentsElementId')">Services</button>
```

the function:

```
  scroll(id: string) {
    let el = document.getElementById(id);
    console.log(id);
    el!.scrollIntoView();
  }
```

And then I have an another component, which has the element, where I would like to scroll. Lets call this **B element**:

```
<section class="page-section" id='anotherComponentsElementId'>lets gooo</section>
```

How can I scroll from A element to B element?
Currently the code doesnt work, because in the function the id is null. Would you be so kind to help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to a specific Element Using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739126/scroll-to-a-specific-element-using-html)

Comment: Dear @Le____ ! Thank you for your instantly fast answer. For me for some reason it doesnt work, i have no idea why. Would you be so kind to make a stackblitz if you are confident that it is working? In my case the URL is changing but no "jump to the HTML with or without animation" is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add `onclick="location.href='#elementid'"` in your button.

```html
<input id='top' type="button" onclick="location.href='#A'" value="go to A" />
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='#B'" value="go to B" />
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='#C'" value="go to C" />
<br><br>
<section id='A' style='background:red'>section 1</section>
<p>line</p>
<p>line</p>
<p>line</p>
<p>line</p>
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='#top'" value="back to top" />
<br><br>
<section id='B' style='background:green'>section 2</section>
<p>line</p>
<p>line</p>
<p>line</p>
<p>line</p>
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='#top'" value="back to top" />
<br><br>
<section id='C' style='background:blue'>section 3</section>
<p>line</p>
<p>line</p>
<p>line</p>
<p>line</p>
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='#top'" value="back to top" />
<br><br><br>
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why location.href='#elementid'" works but it works. So thank you very much sir!

Comment: Add 'onclick' content in an html tag is the same as add an onlclick eventlistener to the element: the content is read as Javascript. It means `location.href='#top'` is a Javascript line changing the last part of the URL.