# Scroll to element in mat-dialog using fragment link

Tags: angular, mat-dialog, url-fragment

I'm implementing a list of posts in a dialog, where a post can quote another post. I would like to be able to scroll to the quoted post when clicking a link which looks like this:

`<a href="/thread/123#123">123</a>`

However, when I click the link, it closes the dialog instead of scrolling to the correct post.

I already have

`scrollPositionRestoration:'enabled', anchorScrolling: 'enabled'`

in my route options.

How can I keep the dialog open and scroll to the selected post?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to a specific Element Using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739126/scroll-to-a-specific-element-using-html)

Comment: No, I implemented that. If I put my code on a page without a dialog it works. Only when there is a dialog it seems to reload the route or something, closing the dialog.