# How to scroll to an element of a list in react native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I was wondering if it was possible to scroll to an element of a list depending on another element of the list (ex : you avec a list [a,b,c,d], you put a touchableopacity with a b c d as text touchable and then you have multiple view, 1 for each elements of your list, and those view are created with a data.map. You then want that when you click on b, it will lead to the view of the element b)
I have tried using react-native-scroll-to-element from [How to scroll to a specific element that can be modified? (React Native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72534384/how-to-scroll-to-a-specific-element-that-can-be-modified-react-native) but it doesn't seems to work.

Here is the code :

```
<View>
  {letter.map((letter) => {
    return (
      <SpecialView>
        <Text
          onPress={() => {
            viewRef.current?.focus();
            scrollLetter = letter.name;
          }}
        >
          {letter.name}
        </Text>
      </SpecialView>
    );
  })}
</View>
<View>
  {letter.map((letter) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <div>
          <Text>{letter.name}</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 0 }}>
            {(scrollend = letter.name)}
            {/*la lettre actuelle */}
          </Text>
        </div>
      </View>
    );
  })}
</View>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might also try to use [`scrollTo()`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollto) method of React Native's Scroll View.

If I understand your request correctly you should do something like this:

```
const ListPage = () => {
    const itemSize = 400
    const items = [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' }]

    const scrollView = useRef(null)

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View
                style={{
                    padding: 20
                }}
            >
                {items.map((item, index) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        key={`head-${index}`}
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: 'red'
                        }}
                        onPress={() => {
                            scrollView.current.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: itemSize * index, animated: true })
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{item.name}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                ))}
            </View>
            <ScrollView ref={scrollView}>
                {items.map((item, index) => (
                    <View
                        key={`body-${index}`}
                        style={{
                            height: itemSize,
                            backgroundColor: 'green'
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                ))}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: I guess it is deprecated

Comment: @theshubhagrwl there is a yellow box in the RN documentation that says: "Note: The weird function signature is due to the fact that, for historical reasons, the function also accepts separate arguments as an alternative to the options object. This is deprecated due to ambiguity (y before x), and SHOULD NOT BE USED."

So the deprecated method is: `scrollTo(0, 10)`