# React Native How to scroll to an element in a list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scroll

##### What I am trying to do:

When a user clicks on a notification for reports, open the product results screen, where reports are rendered. I want it to auto scroll directly to the reports.

The examples confuse me. I don't understand how to pass the report id if I need to create a ref with null value. I also dont understand how to eventually scroll to that element.

```js
const SearchResults = ({route}) => {
    const {ResultsId, reportId} = route.params;
    const ref = useRef(null);
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <Component1 />
        <Component1 />
        <Component1 />
        <Reports ref={ref} reports={reports} reportId={reportId} />
      <ScrollView />
    )
}

const Reports = forwardRef(({reports, reportId}, ref)=> {
    return (
        {reports.map(report=> {
            return <Report ref={ref} reportId={reportId} .../>
            })
    
        }
)
})

const Report = forwardRef(({reportId}, ref)=> {
    return (
        <View ref={ref}>
            <Text>Im a report</Text>
        </View>
        
    )
})
```

Comment: Hi @leanncode, 
Please add map in your list inside the scroll view it will work.

Comment: i dont understand, im not iterating inside anything in my scrollview.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll to an element of a list in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72548396/how-to-scroll-to-an-element-of-a-list-in-react-native)

Comment: in that example the height of the element + the index is passed to scrollTo, but I dont think I can pass an id to it, so I wouldnt know how to calculate the position based on the id