# How to scroll 50px beyond a <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to scroll to a div using HTML, but instead of scrolling to the top of the div, scroll 50px up from the div ?

Ive been following this method taken from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739126/scroll-to-a-specific-element-using-html), but wondered how i could scroll past the div if required. Ideally i would like to do this with just HTML an no JS, but could use JS if required.

HTML

```
<a href="#google"></a>

<div id="google"></div>
```

CSS

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: you can make a named `anchor` and position it 50px below the `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scroll-snap combined with `scroll-margin` can help you

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
}

#google {
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: red;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  scroll-margin: 50px; /* OR -50px based on what you want */
}
```

```html
<a href="#google">Scroll</a>
<div style="height: 800px"></div>
<div id="google"></div>
<div style="height: 800px"></div>
```

Comment: @Andria both of them are in the code (there is an `OR`)